# Implement timeit() in extended class in python

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

Naive programmer: I'm trying to use the timeit module but I don't know how. I have extended the class:

```
class Pt:
   def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class pt_set(Pt):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pts = []
    def distance(self):
        ...
        ...
     return d,(pt1,pt2)
```

And I have made an object:

```
new_points = Pt_set()
```

then calling distance:

```
new_points.distance()
```

How can I use the timeit() function on the distance() function?

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), and this is an example taken from there:

```
 def test():
    """Stupid test function"""
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

for complete ref please read the docs.